# Ce quelqu'un / quelqu'un

Tags: vocabulaire

*Ça fait bizarre d’obéir à quelqu’un. Et c’est encore plus bizarre que **ce quelqu’un** semble se soucier sincèrement de moi*.

Pourriez-vous me dire si *ce quelqu’un* est correct ?

Comment: @jlliagre, je ne pense pas que votre version soit vraiment meilleure que la mienne, je vais donc éditer mon titre. Ma version n'est pas incorrecte, et, dans ce cas-là, il est préférable de "laisser respirer" les gens.

Comment: *Perseverare diabolicum*, je ne vais pas me battre pour une majuscule manquante. Je déplore cependant que la réponse que tu as choisie soit incorrecte...

Answer (score 6):

Ici, "ce quelqu'un" ne désigne pas n'importe quelle personne, mais la personne désignée par le précédent "quelqu'un".
On pourrait reformuler de la façon suivante :
*Ça fait bizarre d’obéir à quelqu’un. Et c’est encore plus bizarre que **la personne à laquelle on obéit** semble se soucier sincèrement de moi.*

Comment: Merci beaucoup, c'est ce que je pensais, mais je n'étais pas sûre que la tournure "ce quelqu'un" soit idiomatique.

Comment: En effet, c'est le même en anglais : "I met someone on the road, and that someone looked awfully suspicious."

Answer (score 3):

Ces deux phrases sont parfaitement compréhensibles et idiomatiques. Le registre est courant. Il n'y a pas de raison de vouloir les changer.

On peut noter que *ce quelqu'un* existe aussi depuis longtemps dans la langue soutenue :

> Ce quelqu'un, cette bouche qui parle dans l’ombre, qu'on ne voit pas, mais qu’on entend, ce passant, cet inconnu, cet insolent, c’est la conscience humaine.

Victor Hugo, *Napoléon le Petit*, 1852.

> Entre ce roi affamé et ce peuple étique, il y avait pourtant quelqu'un de riche. Ce quelqu'un, c'était l'Église.

Jules Michelet, *Histoire de France*, 1833-1867.

> Pour moi, je vous l’avoue, si j’étais galant d’une femme qui fût au pouvoir de quelqu'un, je mettrais toute mon étude à rendre ce quelqu'un jaloux, et l’obliger à veiller nuit et jour celle que je voudrais gagner.

Molière, *Le Sicilien ou l'Amour peintre*, 1667

Comment: Merci. Je pense aussi qu'elles sont acceptables, il ne s'agit pas d'un style soutenu.

Comment: J'ai relu vos réponses. Maintenant, je pense que vous avez raison, Sacha et toi. J'ai même ajouté une majuscule au titre. ;) Bien que j'aie hésité. :)

Answer (score 0):

D'après le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/quelqu%27un) l'emploi de « quelqu'un » est correct parce que ce mot est classé en tant que nom.

> II. − Nom. masc. [Marque l'indétermination voulue ou non]
> A. − Au sing.
> 1.[Marque l'indétermination sur l'identité de la pers.]
> a) [Sans compl.] Un être supérieur humain ou céleste, une personne non identifiable. Synon. on (en fonction de suj.), un quidam, je ne sais qui*.
> Quelqu'un frappe à la porte, a appelé au téléphone, est passé, vous demande.
> Sans doute, tu as des entretiens avec quelqu'un, qui est ton dieu (Renan,Drames philos., Caliban, 1878, i, 2, p. 387)

Cependant, s'il se trouve que l'utilisation d'un démonstratif est idiomatique avec ce nom, qui a un pluriel, ce n'est pas un nom à part entière; on ne peut pas dire « Les quelqu'uns aux portes demandent à rentrer. », par exemple.

La formulation d'une idée par ces deux phrases me semble  très mauvaise.

Selon mon point de vue, il y a tout d'abord une anomalie basique, une lourdeur qui devrait être éliminée, et je le ferais comme suit, mais ce n'est pas tout.

- Ça fait bizarre d’obéir à quelqu’un. Et c’est encore plus bizarre **si/lorsque/quand** ce quelqu’un semble se soucier sincèrement de moi.

Lorsque vous dites « Ça fait bizarre d'obéir à quelqu'un. » vous formulez une assertion générale, vous ne parlez pas seulement pour vous-mêmes; si vous ajoutez une idée dans le cadre des éléments de cette constatation, c'est à dire en reprenant des termes de l'assertion première, mais qu'en faisant cela vous changez le point de vue et parlez seulement pour vous-mêmes vous créez un mélange incohérent.

Qu'est-ce que le pronom « ce » (c') remplace ? La réponse est « obéir à quelqu'un »; donc, donné n'importe qui dans le monde qui obéit à quelqu'un, alors que vous n'obéissez pas à ce quelqu'un (très certainement possible), si ce quelqu'un se soucie sincèrement de vous (ce qui en plus possible), alors c'est encore plus bizarre d'obéir à quelqu'un. Ça n'est évidemment pas ce que vous voulez dire. Vous pouvez quand même continuer et énoncer ce qui serait pour vous une vérité générale si vous le faites de la façon suivante.

- Ça fait bizarre d’obéir à quelqu’un. Et c’est encore plus bizarre si/lorsque/quand ce quelqu’un semble se soucier sincèrement de **vous**.

Vous pouvez aussi changer de perspective et rétrécir le champs de vos considérations à vous-même de la façon suivante.

- Ça fait bizarre d’obéir à quelqu’un. Et lorsque cela m'arrive c’est encore plus bizarre si/lorsque/quand ce quelqu’un semble se soucier sincèrement de moi.

---

*Addition suscitée par les commentaires de **[user Oreste](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/44027/ce-quelqu-un-quelqu-un/44029#comment89454_44029)***

« Quelqu'un » dans la première phrase doit être exactement identique à « quelqu'un » dans la seconde. En se penchant de plus près sur les définitions du [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/quelqu%27un) on constate qu'il y a deux définitions (et même trois mais la troisiême ne nous concerne pas). Elles sont répétées ci-dessous en caractères gras et illustrées.

> ♦ **Une présence d'être humain, un être humain quelconque.**
>
> - − J'entends du bruit. − Non, dit Zéno, c'est la bise Qui souffle bêtement et qu'on prend pour quelqu'un (Hugo,Légende, t. 1, 1859, p. 374).
> - Tout d'un coup, j'ai des envies de griffer, de m'étirer violemment et d'écraser les mains de quelqu'un: ce quelqu'un se trouve être Luce, ma voisine (Colette, Cl. école, 1900, p. 165).
>
> ♦ **Une personne en général.**
>
> - Mon attention, quand je suis avec quelqu'un, est de deviner ses idées (Renan,Souv. enf., 1883, p. 152).
> - Si vous voyiez quelqu'un se noyer, est-ce que vous ne lui tendriez pas la main? (Rolland,J.-Chr., Amies, 1910, p. 1161).

Voici tout d'abord des constructions simples qui permettent de mieux se rendre compte des relations. « Quelqu'un » dans la seconde phrase doit avoir la même définition que dans la première (puisqu'on le désigne par « ce »).

- Je l'ai dit à quelqu'un (*une personne en particulier, déf. 1*) ; ce quelqu'un est ma logeuse. (La personne en particulier est ma logeuse.)
- Lorsque je dit ça à quelqu'un il devient fou  (*N'importe qui, déf. 2*) ; je comprends ce quelqu'un. (Je comprends n'importe qui. (*Ceci est faux.*))

Ça fait bizarre d’obéir à quelqu’un (*N'importe qui, déf. 2*). Et c’est encore plus bizarre que ce quelqu’un semble se soucier sincèrement de moi.

Dans la première phrase il s'agit de la seconde définition ; on a donc le modèle de la seconde suite simple ci-dessus. Il y a donc incohérence.

Comment: Je vous remercie pour votre réponse détaillée !

Comment: "C'est bizarre que" est parfaitement admissible, il exige le subjonctif. Cela dit, "si", "lorsque" et "quand" le sont aussi.

Comment: "...vous formulez une assertion générale..." "...vous changez le point de vue et parlez seulement pour vous-mêmes vous créez un mélange incohérent." --- Je comprends ce que vous voulez dire et vous avez raison, pourtant, je ne pense pas que mon "mélange" soit vraiment une faute. À voir... J'ai l'impression que cela reste acceptable.

Comment: "...alors que vous n'obéissez pas à ce quelqu'un (très certainement possible)..." --- Là, j'avoue que je suis un peu perdue, j'au du mal à vous suivre. En fait, voici ce que je voulais dire : d'habitude, je n'écoute personne. Mais cette fois, je le fais, c'est une exception, et je me sens bizarrement. Mais ce qui est encore plus bizarre, ce que la personne qui exerce son autorité sur moi, elle se soucie de moi. Je n'ai écrit que ces deux phrases, en réalité, il y a un texte avant.

Comment: @Oreste Je peux me rallier à votre point de vue que l'utilisation de la conjonction « que » résulte en une phrase grammaticale _et_ dont le sens est suffisamment fidèle à l'idée à exprimer, mais à mon avis ce n'est pas la meilleure construction possible. En ce qui concerne l'incohérence, je dois continuer à m'en tenir à mon jugement initial, lequel j'ai bien peur de ne pas savoir expliquer de la meilleure façon possible. Je vais ajouter une précision à ma réponse.

Comment: Je vous remercie pour votre réponse et votre temps. Maintenant, après votre ajoute, je comprends ce que vous voulez dire. :)

Comment: Bah, j'ai enfin compris, vous avez raison ! C'est ça le problème, vous connaissez les nuances de la langue beaucoup mieux que la plupart des membres, et ceux-ci peignent à vous suivre justement parce que d'habitude on ne prête pas attention à ce genre de détails.

Comment: @Oreste Je dois avouer que l'on ne m'a encore jamais fait de remarques aussi rassurantes et encourageantes que les vôtres et j'en suis très flatté ; quelle que soit leurs pertinences, je vous remercie pour risquer ainsi vos opinions ouvertement.

Comment: @Oreste Je suppose que tu veux dire *ceux-ci **peinent** à vous suivre*...

Comment: @LPH *Quelqu'un* a deux pluriels suivant le sens, *quelques-uns* ou *quelqu'uns*. Rien n'interdit de dire *les quelqu'uns aux portes demandent à rentrer* (c'est à dire: les personnes importantes/connues demandent à rentrer).

Comment: @jlliagre Oui, "peinent", merci ! Mais je ne peux plus éditer...

Comment: Parfois aussi avec l'article au lieu du démonstratif : « Vous savez que j'aime quelqu'un [...]. Lors, quelqu'un... UN autre quelqu'un: UN quelqu'un masculin... s'est mis en travers de ma route... et CE quelqu'un me porte exagérément sur les nerfs » (FARRÈRE) ds. LBU14 à 758R3...